# Deployment of library and contract separately

Tags: solidity

If I import a library in my smart contract where all the functions of that library are “pure internal” then the size of that library will be added to my smart contract and the size exceeds “eip-170” which prevents deployment.

What happens if I deploy the library separately with “pure public” functions and then deploy the actual contract separately? What are the pros and cons of this approach? I know that uniswap has done this for their periphery NFT contract.

We are not concerned about the deployment cost. We are only concerned about the gas cost of running the contract functions. How would separate deployment affect the gas cost of running contract functions which run library functions frequently? How much? Is it significant? Even for recent compiler versions?

How do we inform the contract of the library’s deployment address? In Brownie, this happens automatically and I don’t need to hardcode or set the library address later in the contract. Is it also the case in actual deployment?